# search and delete multiple lines including the matched line

Tags: vim

text file:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Now I want to search for the content `c` and delete the matched line and the another line immediately before it, that is, I want to delete the line `b` and `c`, I've tried `:g/c/ .,-1 d`, but it didn't work. How to make it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good idea, bad syntax. :) This should do it:

```
:g/c/-1,.d
```

Comment: The `.` and the `1` can be assumed. E.g. `:g/c/-,d`

Comment: @PeterRincker: TIL. Even better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace:

```
:%s/.*\nc\n//gc
```

If there is some text after c, you can use:

```
:%s/.*\nc.*\n//gc
```